# How to close a pop_up for all the time when click on close button on pop_up?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

1) listing.html.erb

```
<a class="book_btn" role="button" href="/web/sign_in_user?onward_schedule_id=<%=onward_schedule_id%>&return_schedule_id=<%=return_schedule_id%>&return_date=<%=params[:return_date]%>&is_from_book_link=true" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popup_div" data-remote="true"> Book </a>
```

2) On click of Book one pop_up is coming.

3) On Pop_up one close button is there. When user will click on close button pop_up will 
go off.

4) But When user again click on Book button pop_up should not come, instead of pop_up it should proceed next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose when the user clicks on the close button, that time remove some attributes from the button tag. Like this

```
$("close_button").click(function(){
    // Here the code which will close your popup and then
    $(".book_btn").removeAttr("data-toggle").removeAttr("data-target");
});
```

The above line will permanently remove these attributes so the pop up will not show for that user again and will process next.

Just give a try and see what happens.

Comment: I am glad that I was able to help. Thank You.